# Are rates a scalar, a vector or both?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, definition, differentiation, vector-fields

Are all rates in physics a **scalar**, a **vector** or **both**?

It seem to me like all rates in science are **vectors**.

Examples of rate that are **vectors** are rate of charge flow, rate of heat transfer, rate of mass flow, rate of change of displacement and rate of water entering a water tank (+ve for water entering the tank and -ve for water leaving the tank).

Are there rates in science that are **scalar**?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rate is the same shape as the underlying quantity.

For example, the rate of position (which is a vector) is the velocity vector.

But the rate of temperature change (which is a scalar) is also a scalar.

Derivatives and integrals do not change the shape of a quantity.

Comment: For rate of change of temperature, a +ve rate of change would mean an increase in temperature and a -ve temperature would mean a decrease in temperature. If that is the case, wouldn't $\frac{dT}{dt}$ be vector with just one element?

Comment: A vector with one element is a scalar. There is no distinction.